# Why there is one line of code for DAC buffer settings STM32?

Tags: stm32, dac

I'm trying to enable or disable two DAC outputs of STM32F407 board. STM32CubeMX tools shows the following options:

[image]

Above I choose both output buffers as Enable.

And the auto generated code is as follows:

```
static void MX_DAC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN DAC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END DAC_Init 0 */

  DAC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN DAC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END DAC_Init 1 */
  /** DAC Initialization
  */
  hdac.Instance = DAC;
  if (HAL_DAC_Init(&hdac) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** DAC channel OUT1 config
  */
  sConfig.DAC_Trigger = DAC_TRIGGER_NONE;
  sConfig.DAC_OutputBuffer = DAC_OUTPUTBUFFER_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_DAC_ConfigChannel(&hdac, &sConfig, DAC_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** DAC channel OUT2 config
  */
  if (HAL_DAC_ConfigChannel(&hdac, &sConfig, DAC_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DAC_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END DAC_Init 2 */

}
```

And in [this](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00173145-description-of-stm32l4l4-hal-and-lowlayer-drivers-stmicroelectronics.pdf) HAL document, it says:

[image]

My question is in the generated code there is no separate codes for DAC1 and DAC2. There is only:

*sConfig.DAC_OutputBuffer = DAC_OUTPUTBUFFER_ENABLE;*

How come one line of code sets both DAC output buffer types?

Comment: The line of code you're looking at is only loading values into the `sConfig` struct. That same struct is then used in `HAL_DAC_ConfigChannel` for both `DAC_CHANNEL_1` and `DAc_CHANNEL_2`. Just look at the comments in the code which CUBE_MX generated for you...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's only a matter of how the code is written.

The structure `sConfig` is created once, and used twice when calling `HAL_DAC_ConfigChannel()`, once for each channel. Since both channels have the same settings, this works fine.

If the two channels had different settings, `sConfig` would have been modified between the two usages.